# Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a HelloWorld Java Spring MVC App that is using Hibernate and a MySQL back end. All of the nouns in the last sentence are new to me save the first word.

I am getting this error:

```
Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

My jpaContext file looks contains this:

```
<!-- Properties specific to Hibernate -->
<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></entry> 
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </map>
</property>
```

If I comment out the line

```
org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

My app will create the annotated tables referenced in the Java code.

However, I am following a demo in which presumably a different version of MySQL was used than what I have installed.

If I run the following in MySql:

```
select version()
```

This is returned:

```
'5.6.23-log'
```

How can the above problem line be modified to tell Hibernate which dialect of MySql I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of **hibernate.dialect** key is wrong. It should be org.hibernate.**dialect**.MySQL5InnoDBDialect.

org.hibernate.dialect Class MySQL5InnoDBDialect

```
java.lang.Object
  extended by org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
      extended by org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          extended by org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
              extended by org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

So the correct entry will be

```
<entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
```